# Onmousemove, onmouseover and onmouseenter. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: javascript, html

This code works for onmousemove and onmouseover but it doesn't work for onmouseenter.

If I move the pointer on the second div it remains "second". Why?

I don't understand.

```js
var movecounter = 0;
var entercounter = 0;
var overcounter = 0;
onmousemove = myFunction1;
onmouseenter = myFunction2;
onmouseover = myFunction3;

function myFunction1() {
  movecounter++;
  document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "MouseMove: " + movecounter;
}

function myFunction2() {
  entercounter++;
  document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = "MouseEnter: " + entercounter;
}

function myFunction3() {
  overcounter++;
  document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = "MouseOver: " + overcounter;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="first">first</div>

  <br>

  <div id="second">second</div>

  <br>

  <div id="third">third</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

The `onmouseenter` you are using is the event of the global `Window` itself and might not work as intended. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#Event_handlers for all available event handlers of the `Window`.
Not all event handler support all the possible events defined by `GlobalEventHandlers`.

The easyest fix is to bind the event to a element you want listen to (for example the document or the body element).

In general:

- `mousemove`: Will trigger as soon the pointer moves inside the element the event is bound to.
- `mouseover`: Will be triggered as soon as you move over an element the event is bound to or any other child element. for every "change" a new event will be emitted.
- `mouseenter`: Will be triggered as soon as the pointer enters the element the event is bound to. it will only trigger again if the pointer beforehand leaves the element.

```js
var movecounter = 0;
var entercounter = 0;
var overcounter = 0;
document.body.onmousemove = myFunction1;
document.body.onmouseenter = myFunction2;
document.body.onmouseover = myFunction3;

function myFunction1(){
  movecounter++;
  document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "MouseMove: " + movecounter;
}

function myFunction2(){
  entercounter++;
  document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = "MouseEnter: " + entercounter;
}

function myFunction3(){
  overcounter++;
  document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = "MouseOver: " + overcounter;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="first">first</div>

    <br>

    <div id="second">second</div>

    <br>

    <div id="third">third</div>
  </body>
</html>
```